How can I Append Test Results from Parallel Execution in Pytest-xdist?
I am currently running multiple test suites in parallel using pytest-xdist to speed up the testing process. Each test suite executes independently and logs its results directly to the database. However, this approach results in multiple entries in the database, one for each test suite, which makes it difficult to manage and analyze the overall test outcome.
here is my paramtetrize code:
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # Check if the function or class is marked with 'plan'


    #logging.info(metafunc.config.getoption("--buildno"))
    
    test_plan = load_test_data()

    if test_plan['testType'] == 'plan':

        if "suite_data" in metafunc.fixturenames:
            if "testPlan" in test_plan and "testSuites" in test_plan["testPlan"]:
                test_suites = test_plan["testPlan"]["testSuites"]
                metafunc.parametrize("suite_data", test_suites, ids=[suite["testSuiteID"] for suite in test_suites])
            else:
                raise KeyError("Missing 'testSuites' in 'testPlan'")

here is the test runner:
class TestPlanRunner:
    @pytest.mark.plan
    
    def test_plan_runner(self, test_build_runner_config, suite_data):

        test_plan = test_build_runner_config.get_test_plan()
        suite_id = suite_data.get("testSuiteID")

        suite_data = next(suite for suite in test_plan["testSuites"] if suite["testSuiteID"] == suite_id)
        result = template_test_suite_run(test_build_runner_config, suite_data)


        suite_data['result'] = result  
        

        all_suites_passed = True
        
        if not suite_data['result']:
            all_suites_passed = False

        test_plan_id = test_plan['testPlanID']
    
        if all_suites_passed:

            data = {'testPlanID': test_plan_id, 'result': 'passed'}
            update_plan_result(data)
        else:
            data = {'testPlanID': test_plan_id, 'result': 'failed'}    
            update_plan_result(data)

        logger.info(f">>>>>> TEST PLAN RESULT: {data} <<<<<<")

here is the output:
INFO - >>>>>> TEST PLAN RESULT: {'testPlanID': 'test-plan', 'result': 'failed'} <<<<<<

INFO - >>>>>> TEST PLAN RESULT: {'testPlanID': 'test-plan', 'result': 'passed'} <<<<<<

INFO - >>>>>> TEST PLAN RESULT: {'testPlanID': 'test-plan', 'result': 'passed'} <<<<<<

INFO - >>>>>> TEST PLAN RESULT: {'testPlanID': 'test-plan', 'result': 'passed'} <<<<<<

I tried appending the results of each suite, but it didn’t work as expected. I want to be able to gather the entire results of all the suites and update the database once.
